# How to write text into a file with different font-sizes using Python?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, rtf

How to write Text into a File using Python, where different parts of the Text has different font-size (Title, Sub-Title, content). How to place a picture in the file using Python?

Comment: tried anything yet? please do share if anything done by yourself?

Comment: You need to decide on a file format before you can proceed anywhere with this.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a programming language capable of manipulating text as variables. It does not provide a graphics engine to achieve what you are asking.

You need to decide which output format you want your file to be in, example: .html and then format the output as such.

For example, you can create a python file in html like this:

```
file_handle = open("test.html", "w+b")
html = "<h1>I am a big header</h1><h2>I am a smaller header</h2><h6>I am the smalles header</h6>"
file_handle.write(html)
file_handle.close()
```

Next, navigate to your folder and open test.html in any browser.

As for the images, I suggest you go to:

[[1]: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

for the text, I would write out different lines try this using turtle:

```
h1 = 10
txt = 5
turtle.write('<example',font('Arial,h1,'normal')
```

so on and so on.
as for the images, I don't know.